# Vuejs class binding

Tags: class, binding, vue.js

I have this in my class which works fine

**v-bind:class="{ 'myclass': MyVarIsTrue}">**

However I would like to do an evaluation other than true/false, otherwise I would have to write multiple methods to evaluate.

Can I either

Evaluate inline

**{ 'myclass': if MyVar > 20}**

Or Use a  method

**{ 'myclass': isGreater(20) }**

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question I can compare to a computed value, which is pretty cool.

v-bind:class="{ 'myclass':  $parent.myComputed Value  > 0 }">